# How to make local /etc/group take priority over LDAP when names collide?

Tags: centos, ldap, openldap

We have a working LDAP set up. However we hit a problem recently due to some user names and group names existing both in the local files and in LDAP. Specifically the apache user and group existed both in:

- `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group`
- LDAP as both user and group

After a recent yum update (CentOS 5), it appeared that the group ID of the process had changed from the value in `/etc/group` to the value in LDAP (while the user ID remained the ID from `/etc/passwd`). As some of the files needed by httpd were owned by user root, with group apache (from `/etc/group`) but not world readable, this caused problems.

Note that we already have `nss_initgroups_ignoreusers apache,...` in both `/etc/ldap.conf` and `/etc/openldap/ldap.conf`. Also, in `/etc/nsswitch.conf` we have

```
passwd:     files ldap
group:     files ldap
shadow:     files ldap
```

and the rest of the normal bits and bobs.

So if a name exists in both LDAP and the local files, is there a way to ensure that the ID from the local files will take precedence over the ID in LDAP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if it's a typo in your example but the group database is called `group` and not `groups`.

You should be able to force the search to stop after a successful lookup e.g.

```
passwd:    files [SUCCESS=return] ldap
group:     files [SUCCESS=return] ldap
```

The above should be the deafult action anyway so you should confirm that what you are looking for really is in the `files`.

> NOTES
>          Within each process that uses nsswitch.conf, the entire  file 
>   is  read
>          only  once;  if  the  file  is later changed, the process will
>   continue
>          using the old configuration.

Comment: The groups was a typo, corrected in question now. Will look into this in more detail tomorrow at work.

Comment: I also had to clear the **nscd** cache.  This didn't happen during service restart, so I had to do it manually: `sudo mv /var/cache/nscd/passwd{,.old}` .